# How to find specific columns from table?

Tags: sql, oracle

The columns in my table are:

```
BWT_ID
BWT_NAME
BWT_SALARY
ADDRESS
JOB-TYPE
GENDER
```

How do I fetch columns whose name starts with "BWT"?

Comment: Do you mean some way other than `SELECT BWT_ID, BWT_NAME, BWT_SALARY FROM Table`?

Answer (score 3):

Use [all_tab_columns](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm)

```
 SELECT all_tab.COLUMN_NAME
 FROM all_tab_columns all_tab
 WHERE all_tab.TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
 AND all_tab.COLUMN_NAME like 'BWT%'
```

> ALL_TAB_COLUMNS describes the columns of the tables, views, and clusters accessible to the current user.

Comment: If the session is connected to the schema owner, then a query upon user_tab_columns takes less typing. I'm betting you know this but it's highly likely the OP does not. If there are multiple schemas that contain such a table, then without the OWNER being projected, the output might look confusing.